# Start Federated Engine In MySQL 8.0

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I am struggling to connect with the federated engine on MySQL 8.0.

[image]

As in the above image you can see the federated engine is not supported.

I tried the solution provided for MySQL 5.1.44 where the same question
was asked and I have added the following thing:

```
[mysqld]
federated
```

but this is not working and I am not able to find a solution for this problem.

Can you please help me with it?

Comment: Is your server complied with FEDERATED engine enabled? Try to start service with `--federated` option..

Comment: where should I execute this command? I mean the directory path for cmd?

Comment: Find the place where your MySQL service (Windows) or daemon (.nix) is started. Stop server. Edit starting command line, add mentioned option. Start server. Check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom build of MySQL with the federated storage engine enabled (see also [16.8 The FEDERATED Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html) in the MySQL documentation. Once you have that build you can [create a table like any other](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-create.html), but with the federated storage engine to hold the data.

Comment: Actually, I figured out what was the problem I tried everything but nothing was working it was because I never restarted the MySQL Service in Windows Services after doing the changes. I still appreciate your all answers as it helped understand a lot of things.